# How to avoid problem of last unpaired element while building merkle tree

Tags: ethereum, merkle-tree

Can we avoid problem of last unpaired data element while building merkle tree for ethereum blockchain? I know that there's way to solve this problem in blockchain, we must duplicate last element, but this is issue which can be used to attack network.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you're referring to?

Comment: Do you mean examples with bitcoin?